# Ruby: What is "Self" inside "If" Statement of Instance Method

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement, self, instance-methods

**What does "self" refer to** when it's inside an "if" statement (or is it called block?) that is inside an instance method?

I'm referring to my code in the last method: "**apply_discount**"

I thought it'd get me the @total and @discount instance variables, but it's not doing so

*I'm assuming it's the "if" statement itself or maybe the method itself since it's not doing what I thought it would.*

**So, basically**, how would I get these variables from the my place in the "if" statement I'm referring to by using "self"?

Or should I use another way?

```
class CashRegister

    attr_accessor :total, :discount

    def initialize(discount = 0)
        @total = 0
        @discount = discount
    end

    def add_item(title, price, quantity = 0)
        if quantity > 0
            self.total += (price * quantity)
        else
            self.total += price
        end
    end

    def apply_discount
        # total = self.total
        # discount = self.discount
        if self.discount > 0
            self.total = self.total - (self.total * (self.discount / 100.0))
            "After the discount, the total comes to $#{self.total}."
        else
            "There is no discount to apply."
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code works, or at least does what I think you want. `total` and `discount` accessors are being correctly accessed (and do indeed give you the `@total` and `@discount` instance variables).

Comment: `self.total =` should call the method `total=(some_value)` on your instance, which in turn (since you have an `attr_accessor`) sets the value of `@total`. What's causing you to say that it isn't working?

Comment: My bad guys, it must have been causing trouble only because I had not yet changed "100.0" from 100.

Comment: Let's find out. `class CashRegister; def apply_discount; if true; puts "self=#{self}"; end; end; end; cr = CashRegister.new #=> self=#<CashRegister:0x007f931c056520>; cr.apply_discount` prints `self=#<CashRegister:0x007f931c056520>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing it always referred to, the object the method was called on. Your code works fine.

```
cr = CashRegister.new(10)
cr.add_item("Sporkle", 10, 2)
cr.add_item("Glagnar's Human Rinds", 15, 1)
puts cr.total     # 35
cr.apply_discount
puts cr.total     # 31.5
```

---

As a side note, you can simplify your code to add an item, there's no need to special case a single item; `anything * 1` is `anything`. Also 0 is an odd default, adding nothing is almost never what you want, making it the default will hide mistakes. Either remove the default, or make it something useful like 1.

```
def add_item(title, price, quantity = 1)
    self.total += price * quantity
end
```

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. I realized that it must have been buggy because I had not yet changed "100.0" from "100" when i tested it. My bad, but glad for the code tip.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `self` refers to the instance of the object itself, in this case the object is `CashRegister`. The constructor method `initialize` sets up the instance variables (the @ means instance variable), while the `attr_accessor` sets up the mutator and accessor methods which allows you to use self.variable within the object and also write and retrieve those variables directly from the object, for example `cashregister.total` would give whatever you set that to

Removing attr_accessor from the top you would get the following error:

```
:12:in `add_item': undefined method `total' for #<CashRegister:0x00000001b77c98 @total=0, @discount=10> (NoMethodError)
        from answer.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

This is the concept is called "encapsulation". The variables within the object are private to that object and you need a specific method to change them and retrieve them.

The attr_accessor shortcut method can be written in the following matter as well:

```
class CashRegister

def initialize(discount = 0)
    @total = 0
    @discount = discount
end

def total #accessor
  @total
end

def total=(value) #mutator
  @total=value
end

def discount #accessor
  @discount
end

def discount=(value) #mutator
  @discount=value
end

def add_item(title, price, quantity = 0)
    if quantity > 0
        self.total += (price * quantity)
    else
        self.total += price
    end
end

def apply_discount
    # total = self.total
    # discount = self.discount
    if self.discount > 0
        self.total = self.total - (self.total * (self.discount / 100.0))
        "After the discount, the total comes to $#{self.total}."
    else
        "There is no discount to apply."
    end
end
```

end

Hope that helps you some.